# Get element based on string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I am creating a web api using mvc 6. now i am trying to get a element from my db. the key in this table is a string (email address). I do not have access to this database so i cant change the key of this table.

Now when creating a demo webapi i was able to create a controller to extract items based on a key which was an int. But when trying to get a element by a string the program crashes.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {    

        [HttpGet("{id:string}", Name = "GetByIdRoute")]
        public IActionResult GetById (string id)
        {
            var item = _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }
   }
```

when trying to access this path (example.com/api/Todo/key) key being the string i get an exception in my startup.cs

the exception in the browser reads:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   The constraint entry 'id' - 'string' on the route 'api/Todo/{id:string}' could not be resolved by the constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver'.

the part of the startup.cs where the code breaks is:

```
// Add MVC to the request pipeline.
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });   

            });
```

i cant seem to figure out why i ain't allowed to get a item by a key which is a string.
is this even possible and if so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you definitely need the `:string` part at all?

Comment: You can remove `:string` it's used by default.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just remove `:string`. You're not really constraining the value of the `id` anyway - it's already a string in the URL.

[This fairly old blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-constraints) lists the available constraints - and you can see there's no `:string` constraint, because you don't need there to be.

The constraints are used to give "more specific" constraints a priority - e.g. "If that part of the URL is the string representation of a `DateTime`, use this route" - but as everything is a string (in a URL), there's nothing that a constraint of `:string` would make it more specific than, if you see what I mean.

Comment: This also applies to Razor Pages in .NET Core 2.0, I guess it's fairly the same process of putting all the pieces together.

Comment: The updated link is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-constraints

Comment: @tony: Updated - it would probably have been better to propose an edit yourself though.